# Reading multiple csv of same format in a data frame

Tags: r, csv, macros, dataframe

I need to run the same set of code for multiple CSV files. I want to do it with the same with macro. Below is the code that I am executing, but results are not coming properly. It is reading the data in 2-d format while I need to run in 3-d format.

```
lf = list.files(path = "D:/THD/data", pattern = ".csv",
                full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)
ds<-lapply(lf,read.table)
```

Comment: Maybe you need `read.csv` instead of `read.table`. But without any idea what the files look like (i.e., input and your intended output), it's pretty difficult to help you.

Comment: You need to pass the appropriate parameters to `read.table`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is going to be useful but one of the way I do is:

```
 ##Step 1 read files 

       mycsv = dir(pattern=".csv")

        n <- length(mycsv) 

    mylist <- vector("list", n) 

    for(i in 1:n) mylist[[i]] <- read.csv(mycsv[i],header = T)
```

then I useually just use apply function to change things, for example,

```
 ##  Change coloumn name
    mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) {names(x) <- c("type","date","v1","v2","v3","v4","v5","v6","v7","v8","v9","v10","v11","v12","v13","v14","v15","v16","v17","v18","v19","v20","v21","v22","v23","v24","total") ; return(x)}) 

    ##  changing type coloumn for weekday/weekend

    mylist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) {
        f = c("we", "we", "wd", "wd", "wd", "wd", "wd")
        x$type = rep(f,52, length.out = 365)
        return(x)
    }) 


and so on.
```

Then I save with this following code again after all the changes I made (it is also sometime useful  to split original file name and rename each files to save with a part of file name so that I can track each individual files later)

```
##  for example some of my file had a pattern in file name such as "201_E424220_N563500.csv",so I split this to save with a new name like this:    

mylist <-lapply(1:length(mylist), function(i) {
    mylist.i <- mylist[[i]]     
    s = strsplit(mycsv[i], "_" , fixed = TRUE)[[1]]     
    d = cbind(mylist.i[, c("type", "date")], ID = s[1], Easting = s[2], Northing = s[3], mylist.i[, 3:ncol(mylist.i)])     
    return(d) 
})

for(i in 1:n)    
    write.csv(file = paste("file", i, ".csv", sep = ""),    mylist[i], row.names = F)
```

I hope this will help. When you get some time pleaes read about the PLYR package as I am sure this will be very useful for you, it is a very useful package with lots of data analysis options. PLYR has apply functions such as:

```
## l_ply   split list, apply function and discard result 
## ldply   split list, apply function and return result in data frame 
## laply   split list, apply function and return result in an array
```

for example you can use the ldply to read all your csv and return a data frame simething like:

```
data = ldply(list.files(pattern = ".csv"), function(fname) {

  j = read.csv(fname, header = T)

  return(j)

})
```

So here J will be your data frame with all your csv files data.

Thanks,Ayan

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply, i tried through above and few other ways also but i am getting NULL value as output.

Comment: is there any chance you could give some sample files so that  I can write codes to suite your purpose?